# How to click on a button webelement using css_selector with Selenium webdriver for identical button types

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For a HTML,

```
<div class="some-class">
    <button type="button">Ok</button>
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
```

Both button type are the same for two different buttons so how can I click on the Ok button using find_element_by_css_selector? I tried driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.some-class > button.button[1]").click() but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `div.some-class > button.button` as selector becasue `find_element_by_css_selector` return the first matched WebElement:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.some-class > button").click()
```

If you want be explicit use `:nth-child(1)` or `:first-child`.

**UPDATE**

selector was wrong. Selector should be `div.some-class > button[type=button]` or simply `div.some-class > button`.

Comment: This is the right answer. If you wanted to click on the Cancel button, you would do `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("...")` and then select the second item in the list or use `nth-child(2)`

Comment: So I replaced [1] in `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.some-class > button.button[1]").click()` with (1) but I get `Unable to locate element`

Comment: @LP, Not `(1)`, but `:nth-child(1)`.

Comment: @falsetru: I tried `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.some-class > button.button:nth-child(1)").click()` and the other one as well but the same result. Am I still not using it correctly?

Comment: @LP, Let me know the url. Or can you upload the html to somewhere?

Comment: @falsetru: I wish I could but I'm not authorised to. The HTML is exactly the same as what I've quoted above but it works fine if there's just one html tag. However, for tags with the same name it's not working even with your solution.

Comment: @LP, I got it. Replace `button.button` with `button` or `button[type=button]`. I thought it was `class=button` ;)

Comment: @falsetru: How can I make this work in the case of 'div's of the same name? the nth-child() concept does not seem to work. eg: There are 4 `div class="ctrl-gp er req"` each containing one `div class="ctrls"` each containing a `<p class="help">TEXT_TO_VERIFY</p>`. thanks!

Comment: @LP, You can use `find_elements_by_css_selector(...)[nth]` (there's `s`).

Comment: @falsetru: how could I find them individually as the text to verify can differ in each case?