# Selenium Python find element by CSS Selector

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-sku-id="4523156" style="padding:0 8px">
  <svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="width:16px;height:16px;margin-bottom:-2px;margin-right:9px;fill:currentColor">
    <use href="/~assets/bby/_img/int/plsvgdef-frontend/svg/cart.svg#cart" xlink:href="/~assets/bby/_img/int/plsvgdef-frontend/svg/kurt.svg#cart"></use>
  </svg>
  button selector
</button>
```

I am trying to understand CSS selectors because the button I want to press using XPATH seems to change some of the values in HTML or is inconsistent between pages.

I have referenced this post:

[How to click on a button webelement using css_selector with Selenium webdriver for identical button types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744094/how-to-click-on-a-button-webelement-using-css-selector-with-selenium-webdriver-f)

Based on that post I would attempt to find it using a CSS Selector like so:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".btn btn-primary[type='button']")
```

Comment: Could you show us the url of your page?

Comment: You selector not valid. Please try `.find_elements_by_css_selector("button.btn.btn-primary")` or `.find_elements_by_css_selector("button.btn.btn-primary[type='button']")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css selector is a little bit wrong:
Instead of `".btn btn-primary[type='button']"`

Try to use This :

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary[type='button']")
```

Note that i added `.`, this is because css selectors are slightly different the the way you name classes in html... whenu want to check many classes in the same element, with css selector you divide them with dots and no spaces...

Comment: adir I believe I needed to include "button" before the "." as well but other than that this worked! I did not know that any spaces count as a new class? Does this mean I should always use a "." if there is a space within the " " of a class?

Comment: if you intend to call the child (descendant) u should use a space and dot, if u want to call someone with multiple classes (its not secesarry, its usefull to be more specific) u add another class name and dot without space...

Comment: I have another question @adir abargil how do I work with a class which has a space at the end of it? <button class="btn btn-primary " type="button"... would it still be

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary [type='button']") just including the space?

Comment: Space at the end means nothing... and as i was trying to say, to access element you dont have to use all the class names it got.. just any of it (or other way to idetify that specific component) for example in your case: just `".btn”` would do the work too... when you add the space this willruin your selector, you better look for a css selectors toturial because it suppost to be simple and you shouldnt guess how it os working...